# Why would Ashkenazim read a "double" haftarah for Parshat Pekudei in Israel?

Tags: minhag, eretz-yisrael, haftarah, pekudei

All printed *chumashim* that I've seen list the following consecutive selections as the Ashkenazi *hafatarot* for Vayakhel and Pekudei:

- Vayakhel: Melachim I 7:40-50
- Pekudei: Melachim I 7:51-8:21

(And see [this list](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%94#%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA) on Hebrew Wikipedia which says the same.)

However, this (leap) year on Parshat Pekudei I witnessed an Ashkenazi synagogue in Israel read both of these *haftarot* consecutively i.e. the *haftarah* for Parshat Pekudei consisted of Melachim I 7:40-8:21.

I subsequently saw [this page](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99#%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%94) on Hebrew Wikipedia, which notes that such is the Ashkenazi practice in Israel (except for in a year with two *shabbatot chanukah*, when Melachim I 7:40-50 was already read as the *haftarah* for the second *shabbat chanukah*).

What is the history of and the reason for this practice? (Why) is it unique to communities in Israel?

---

### Some (possibly helpful) background

In most non-leap years Vayakhel and Pekudei are joined and are read together with either Parshat Parah or Parshat HaChodesh. In a non-leap year when they are separate, Vayakhel coincides with Parshat Parah and Pekudei with Parshat HaChodesh.

Thus in a non-leap year the *haftarot* of neither Vayakhel nor Pekudei are read.

In a leap year, Vayakhel and Pekudei are read separately, but one of the two weeks always coincides with Parshat Shekalim.

Thus, in a leap year, one and only one of the *haftarot* of Vaykahel and Pekudei are read.

The printed Ashkenazi *haftarah* for Vayakhel is the same as that of the second *shabbat chanukah*.

The printed Ashkenazi *haftarah* for Pekudei consists of the same selection as that of the second day of Sukkot (in the Diaspora) with two extra verses at the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

As you noted, the generally-cited Ashkenazic *haftarah* for Parshat Pekudei is from Melachim I 7:51-8:21. However, there are two additional customs to be aware of, which may go some way to answering your question.

1. There exists an Ashkenazic custom in the Diaspora to read Melachim I 7:40-8:1 as the *haftarah* for Pekudei. This is brought down by [Maharil (Customs of the Four Parshiyot)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8918&st=&pgnum=115) in the name of Maharash, and is subsequently quoted by [Elya Rabbah (685:23)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7767&st=&pgnum=435). (In contrast, this custom is not mentioned by [Levush (685:6)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9223&st=&pgnum=261).)

   Maharil explains the rationale for this custom, is that in any event Melachim I 8:2-21 was read as the *haftarah* for the second day of Sukkot, as opposed to Melachim I 7:40-8:1 which would not otherwise be read at all.
2. The Sephardic *haftarah* for Parshat Pekudei is generally assumed to be from Melachim I 7:40-50 (see e.g. [the Wikipedia list](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%94#%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA) you quoted in your question) i.e. the selection normally listed as the Ashkenazic *haftarah* for Parshat Vayakhel.

[R. Y M Tucazinsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Tucazinsky) writes in [Sefer Eretz Yisrael (16)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8789&st=&pgnum=62) that the custom among the *geonei yerushalayim* is to read Melachim I 7:40-8:21. He explains this as an application of Maharil's ruling (to read Melachim I 7:40-8:1) to the situation in Israel, where there is no second day of Sukkot, and thus neither Melachim I 7:40-8:1 nor Melachim I 8:2-21 are read at other times during the year. Thus, on Parshat Pekudei the custom is to read both.

In contrast, [Aderet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliyahu_David_Rabinowitz-Teomim) in a letter quoted in [Yerushatenu vol. II p. 184](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58217&st=&pgnum=182) writes that he was the one to introduce this practice. He writes that he found the Ashkenazic custom in Jerusalem was to read Melachim I 7:40-50, like the Sephardic custom. Aderet believed that the more correct practice was to follow the widespread Ashkenazic custom of Melachim I 7:51-8:21. However, so as not to (totally) depart from the original custom in Jerusalem, he instructed that both *haftarot* be read (i.e. Melachim I 7:40-8:21).

---

As an addendum, we can address a leap year which contains two *shabbatot chanukah* (year type זשה), in which case Melachim I 7:40-50 is read as *haftarah* on the second *shabbat chanukah*.

In such a year, [Birur Halachah vol. 6 (Orach Chayyim 428)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51654&st=&pgnum=188) quotes R. S Z Auerbach and R. S Deblitsky as ruling that the *haftarah* for Parshat Pekudei comprises only Melachim I 7:51-8:21. This seems to follow R. Tucazinsky's approach: since Melachim I 7:40-50 has already been read earlier in the year, there is no need to read it again.

However, somewhat paradoxically, R. Tucazinsky himself had written in Sefer Eretz Yisrael (ibid.) that both *haftarot* (i.e. Melachim I 7:40-8:21) are read, even in a year of type זשה.

This position (to my mind) actually accords better with that of Aderet. The Sephardic *haftarah* for Parshat Pekudei is always Melachim I 7:40-50 (even in a year where that was read on the second *shabbat chanukah*). If the Ashkenazic custom in Jerusalem was in line with this, then Aderet's ruling to add Melachim I 7:51-8:21 on top of the pre-existing reading would apply in every year-type, even in a year of type זשה with two *shabbatot chanukah*.

---

As a second addendum, we can address a leap year in which Parshat Shekalim is read on Pekudei (year types החא and השג), in which case Vayakhel is free to receive its own *haftarah*.

In such a year, almost lists of *haftarot* that I can see (e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%94#%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA)) list only Melachim I 7:40-50 as the *haftarah* for Vayakhel. However, it does seem that even for Vayakhel, there are those in Israel who would read the full "double" haftarah of Melachim I 7:40-8:21. (See for example the claim [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58217&st=&pgnum=182) that R. Tucazinsky in his calendars for leap years always listed Melachim I 7:40-8:21 as the *haftarah* for either Vayakhel or Pekudei, whichever was available. If anyone has access to an old *luach le-eretz yisrael* for a year of type החא or השג (the most recent occurrence was 5774) I would love to see it.)

Again, we can line these two positions up with the two reasons we have given for the custom to read the "double" *haftarah* for Pekudei.

If the reason is to make sure we don't miss either of the two readings in a given year (R. Tucazinsky), then in Israel we would also read them both for Parshat Vayakhel. (In this respect, R. Tucazinsky is consistent - in any leap year, in Israel he tells us that we always read Melachim I 7:40-8:21 on whichever *shabbat* it is possible to do so, thereby ensuring we miss neither reading.)

This is also consistent with the diasporic practice which seems to have developed in Frankfurt to read as the *haftarah* for Parshat Vayakhel Melachim I 7:40-8:1 (i.e. the 'classic' *haftarah* for Vayakhel with two additional verses; note that this custom was never mentioned by Maharil). Presumably, this was done in order that all of the verses would be read during the year, relying on the second day of Sukkot to read Melachim I 8:2-21. (See, for example, [Zichron Chanoch p10](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32024&st=&pgnum=10&hilite=).)

However, following the approach of Aderet, we can understand why the "double" *haftarah* custom only applies to Parshat Pekudei, and not to Parshat Vayakhel. For Pekudei, where the Sephardic custom is to read Melachim I 7:40-50, the Ashkenazim then extended the reading by adding 7:51-8:21. But for Vayakhel, the Sephardim have a different reading (Melachim I 7:13-26). This reading seems never to have been adopted by the Ashkenazim, in which case they would simply read the longstanding, traditional Ashkenazic *haftarah* for Parshat Vayakhel, i.e. Melachim I 7:40-50.